# Закрытие консоли

Tags: c++, visual-studio, консоль

Как настроить visual studio, чтобы консоль не закрывалась. Проблема в том, что использую классы, где деструктор выводит какое-то сообщение. system("pause") и getch() не подходят, так как код не доходит до выполнения деструктора класса. Есть там в настройках где галочку поставить и консоль не закрывалась? Вижу на ютубе, что у кого-то к конце main только return 0, но консоль не закрывается

Comment: Незакрывание консоли - это режим по-умолчанию в VS2017 19, *"деструктор выводит какое-то сообщение"*  - printf-отладка обычно является бесполезной тратой времени

Comment: Ну не знаю, у меня консоль закрывается. А насчет вывода сообщений, мне интересно посмотреть, как что работает

Comment: нужная настройка лежит на странице debugging - general

Comment: Нстройки проекта>Линковщик>Система>Подсистема поставить Console

Comment: Создайте локальную область видимости, типа такого `int main(){ { ... Myclass obj; ...} system("pause");return 0; }`

Comment: Да, вы правы, как по мне это самое оптимальное решение!